# Custom Protocol delegate is nil

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, swift-protocols

I have a strange bug with my delegate being nil and no clue where to check. Maybe someone else had the same issue.

I have this class and protocol:

```
protocol NavigationProtocol: class {
    func pushVC()
}

class LocalNotification: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    weak var delegate: NavigationProtocol? {
        didSet {
            print("was set")
        }
    }
.........

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        self.delegate?.pushVC()
        completionHandler()
    }
```

and in my VC

```
class FinalDecisionViewController: UIViewController {

    var localNotification: LocalNotification!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupNotification()
    }
    
    private func setupNotification() {
        localNotification = LocalNotification()
        localNotification.delegate = self
        localNotification.scheduleNotification(title: "Loan Approval", message: "Congratulations! Your loan has been approved", type: "Loan Approval")
    }


extension FinalDecisionViewController: NavigationProtocol {
    func pushVC() {
        canMoveToNextVC = true
    }
}
```

After the schedule notification is triggered, I’m clicking on it and `didReceive` is called and `self.delegate?.pushVC()` is somehow nil even though the delegate has been set ( message from `didSet` was printed).

Delegate method from extension never triggered since delegate is nil.

I've also printed some messages in `deinit` of each class to see if it's somehow deleted from memory but they weren't , only after I've pop them from vc stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
weak var delegate: NavigationProtocol? {
    didSet {
        print("was set")
        notificationCenter.delegate = self
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
localNotification = LocalNotification()
localNotification.delegate = self
localNotification.notificationCenter.delegate = localNotification
localNotification.scheduleNotification(title: "Loan Approval", message: "Congratulations! Your loan has been approved", type: "Loan Approval")
```

Comment: It's not working. And again I have the notificationCenter.delegate (which is the delegate of the UNUserNotificationCenter ) set in AppDelegate.

`let notifications = LocalNotification()`

`notifications.notificationCenter.delegate = notifications`

I receive the notification but upon clicking on it doesn't trigger my custom one which is nil

Comment: Added a break point inside didReceive with class LocalNotification ????

Comment: Yes! And it did trigger it! but the `self.delegate?.pushVC()` was empty

Comment: https://github.com/marcelfagadariu/LocalNotificationDemo 

First time when run will just need to accept the incoming notification. But run it one more time to see the bug